# Apache Axis cannot find WSDL2Java class

Tags: java, axis, apache-axis

I have used Apache Axis in the past to generate a Java client from a wsdl. Since then I received a new laptop and I am trying to get Axis setup again. I am running Windows 10 and I'm trying the commands in both Git for Windows as well as in the windows command prompt.

My setup is such, I have `AXIS2_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\development\Apache\axis2-1.7.9` and my PATH includes `%AXIS2_HOME%\bin` and `%AXIS2_HOME%`. I have the same setup for Axis 1.4 `AXIS_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\development\Apache\axis-1.4` and PATH includes `%AXIS_HOME%\bin`, `%AXIS_HOME%\bin`.

For Axis2, when I run `$AXIS2_HOME/bin/wsdl2java.sh -cp $AXISCLASSPATH -uri ./SI_Z_EUPM_SHPFLRI_BREAKDOWN_START_OIService.wsdl` in Git BASH my output is simply

```
 Using AXIS2_HOME: /c/Users/aa99988/development/Apache/axis2-1.7.9
 Using JAVA_HOME:  C:\Users\aa99988\development\languages\Java\openJDK_8
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java
```

The same response is given if I set up windows command accordingly.

Regardless of which Axis version I use, I get the same response.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using Apache Axis 1.4 and executing the commands from windows command prompt.